# How to use update to use mouse in my game properly

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm building a chess game now, and I have a problem.
I have this update function for the pawn:

```
public void update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
            if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if ((float)ms.X / 50 >= location.x && (float)ms.X / 50 <= location.x + 1 && (float)ms.Y / 50 >= location.y && (float)ms.Y / 50 <= location.y + 1)
                {
                    if (!draw_spots)
                    {
                        draw_spots = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        draw_spots = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                  spot sp = new spot(ms.X / 50, ms.Y / 50);
                    if (draw_spots)
                    {
                        draw_spots = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

what it is supposed to do is to put draw_spots to true (meaning that the possible moving locations and eating location should be drawn) when pressing the left mouse click. change it to false when i press again so it should stop drawing those. the function work, but sometimes the squares that should turn to blue just flicker and turn off. My guess is that I press the left mouse button for an even number of update sequences (which makes it turn on and then off). any idea on how to solve it?
Thanks!

a video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awb4V1giV2Y&feature=youtu.be
you can see some presses that make the blue line appear and then disappear even though i pressed once

Comment: Is it possible to give us a screenshot / video? So that way it's easier to see what situation you're talking about.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awb4V1giV2Y&feature=youtu.be you can see some presses make the blue line appear and disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself, what i did was as follows.
add a variable called oldms that saves the mouse state from the last update.
then in the if statement I asked if the mouse left key is not pressed, and also if mouse left key was pressed last update. which means, i pressed the mouse and i want it to draw now.

Answer (score 0):

When you write code in an `Update` method you need to think about it as if it was inside an infinite loop like this:

```
while(true)
{
    if (!draw_spots)
    {
        draw_spots = true;
    }
    else
    {
        draw_spots = false;
    }
}
```

When you look at the logic in that simplistic manner it should be easy to see why you're getting the flickering behaviour. It's literally toggling the `draw_spots` variable on and off over and over again.

To keep with the infinite loop analogy lets take a look at what the code should be doing instead. There's essentially two things that should both be true when you want to "draw spots".

1. The left mouse button is pressed
2. The mouse cursor is within the square

Now, lets translate this logic into code.

```
while(true)
{
    var ms = Mouse.GetState();
    var leftButtonPressed = ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed;
    var mouseInsideSquare = (float)ms.X / 50 >= location.x && 
                            (float)ms.X / 50 <= location.x + 1 &&
                            (float)ms.Y / 50 >= location.y &&
                            (float)ms.Y / 50 <= location.y + 1;

    if (leftButtonPressed && mouseInsideSquare)
       draw_spots = true;
    else
       draw_spots = false;
}
```

By keeping things as simple as possible and naming your bits of logic with extra variables the code gets a lot easier to read and understand.

I would even go as far as pulling out even more bits of logic into variables and simply set the value of `draw_spots` to the result like this:

```
    var ms = Mouse.GetState();
    var leftButtonPressed = ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed;
    var mx = ms.X / 50f;
    var my = ms.Y / 50f;
    var mouseInsideSquare = mx >= location.x && 
                            mx <= location.x + 1 &&
                            my >= location.y &&
                            my <= location.y + 1;

    draw_spots = leftButtonPressed && mouseInsideSquare;
```

It's a matter of taste which version of the above code you prefer. The point is to break your code up in a way that makes it easier to understand. I hope that helps.

The only other weird bit of your code is this line:

```
 spot sp = new spot(ms.X / 50, ms.Y / 50);
```

but since the `sp` variable goes out of scope before it's used I'm going to assume you left it there while debugging something and it can be safely deleted.

Comment: Yes you are right i forgot to delete it (It's for something else in the code but i want the mouse working first), I will try what you said. Thanks!
edit: I read again what you wrote, and this code will not work for what i want.
I will explain myself better: I want draw_spots to become true if I press on the left mouse button once and if I press it again I want to make it false. that way, if I press once the possible moves for the piece get drawn, and if I press somewhere else it should turn false so it should stop drawing those. I don't want to hold the left mouse button, just press it once

Comment: what is not like i wanted is the thing that should be true number 2 is okay but number one should be: The left mouse button has been pressed

Comment: To implement the "has been pressed" mode you'd need to introduce another flag that toggles each time the mouse changes state from `ButtonState.Pressed` to `ButtonState.Released` otherwise known as a "click". Games are typically big state machines and your code runs every frame. You'll quite often need to know what happened in the previous frame to decide what is happening in the current frame. Draw yourself a diagram on paper and I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah already did yesterday. I wrote it in a different comment. Thanks for the help!